# Has anybody Implemented ElGamal using OpenSSL or even inside?

Tags: openssl, elgamal

I find out that **OpenSSL** hasn't implemented **ElGamal**. However, currently I need to use **OpenSSL** to implement **ElGamal**. I just wonder if anybody had done it before. And that may help me to reduce my work load. And, if not, is that feasible to implement **ElGamal** inside **OpenSSL**? I had tried to modify the souce code of DSA to implement **ElGamal**, will that yield some troubles that may not be able to find out easily?

Comment: (Yes, I know this is an old question.) ElGamal is ambiguous: The ElGamal *encryption* algorithm has found relatively widespread use in PGP and later OpenPGP. The ElGamal *signature* scheme (which appears to be the topic of this question) has never been widely used, and instead its derivate DSA has become very widespread, because it is cheaper to calculate and has much smaller signatures.

Answer (score -1):

Implementation of ElGamal using OpenSSL BIGNUM is mentioned [here](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~mmarsh/CODEX/src_doc_1.0/ElGamal_8h-source.html) (file list [here](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~mmarsh/CODEX/src_doc_1.0/files.html)). Please see if it can help you.